# Preventing edit of PRIMARY KEY COLUMN value in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, primary-key, identity-column

1. I am importing a row in a datagridview from another one for editing.
2. Edit the values.
3. Save the values.
   But I do not want the user to make changes in the column which is the PRIMARY KEY TABLE.

I have the name of primary key column by

```
string sql = "SELECT ColumnName = col.column_name FROM information_schema.table_constraints tc INNER JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage col ON col.Constraint_Name = tc.Constraint_Name AND col.Constraint_schema = tc.Constraint_schema WHERE tc.Constraint_Type = 'Primary Key' AND col.Table_name = '" + _lstview_item + "'";
            SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(cc.connectionString(cmb_dblist.Text));
            SqlCommand cmd_server2 = new SqlCommand(sql);
            cmd_server2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd_server2.Connection = conn2;
            conn2.Open();
            string ColumnName = (string)cmd_server2.ExecuteScalar();
            //string ColumnName = (string)cmd_server2.ExecuteScalar();
            conn2.Close();
```

and I am building up the update statement as below

```
 u.Append("UPDATE ");
                    u.Append("[Ref].[");
                    u.Append(_lstview_item);
                    u.Append("]");
                    u.Append("SET ");
                    for (i = 0; i < col_no; i++)
                    {
                        u.Append(col_name);
                        u.Append(" = ");
                        u.Append("'");
                        u.Append(col_value);
                        u.Append("'");
                    }
```

How do i detect if the user is changing the value of the primary key column in this situation ?

Comment: can you not just add an if statement in your for loop around your append: if (col_name != ColumnName)

Comment: Make that grid column readonly.

Comment: I cant make it.Because the datagridview is being populated each time i select a table from a table list.

Answer (score 0):

You should not concatenate your SQL statement like that.

Instead use SQL parameters to set the individual properties.

Se an example of how SQLParameters are used in this sample:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

Hope this helps!